# Comparative for Sky Directions

Tags: comparatives

Can you say that something is more souther or more easter than a specific place? How do you give the comparative and superlative forms for North, East, South and West.

I am writing a book, and to explain the positions of my countries I need to use phrases like "A is more *souther* than B", while having looked up, the word "souther" apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: You wouldn't say "more souther" in any case, would you? It would be "more south" or "souther". (But neither of these is correct English.)

Comment: "More southerly", "more easterly" etc as @ Weather Vane points out.

Comment: Is this question only about the comparatives, as the title indicates, or also about the superlatives, which are mentioned in the body of the question? The words *southernmost*, *westernmost*, etc. function as superlatives of *southern*, *western*, etc., even though they are not formed in the way superlatives normally are.

Comment: @jsw29 also superlatives, all forms with sky directions

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think many native speakers would call *north, south, etc* 'sky' directions, I think most of us would call them *compass* directions.

Comment: A is further south than B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add the word **southerly** which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/southerly) says is an

> ADJECTIVE
>
> **1** Lying or moving in a southward position or direction.

So if place B is already considered to be in a southern location then

> A is more southerly than B

Comment: Spot on! Some may get out the Google Ngrams to try and tell you otherwise. But rest assured your answer reflects the Queen's English.

Comment: @WS2 thank you. Someone downvoted this at first but then relented.

Comment: So northerly, easterly and westerly also exist?

Comment: Yes, they do exist, and can also be used as a noun. A "westerly" is wind coming from the west. Note that "southerly" has one difference in that it is not pronounced like "south" but with a **u** as in "but". The others are pronounced as you would expect.

Comment: @AnatolyWein As do south-westerly, north-easterly etc. They are not only used for winds, but for all sorts of things. The winds in southern England are predominantly from the south-west, and so Heathrow Airport is mostly on ***easterlies*** - meaning aircraft land and take off in an easterly direction. When the wind switches to the noth-east (very cold) Heathrow switches to ***westerlies***.

Comment: I don't think I could possibly hear "Florida is more southerly than New York." without thinking "Southerly what?"

Comment: @Greybeard well, New York isn't southerly at all.

Comment: @Greybeard Well "southerly" isn't much used quite like that - though it would be perfectly grammatical. However something like "The more southerly parts of the state are vulnerable to hurricanes" would be a fairly normal usage.

Comment: @WeatherVane

To the comment: "Yes, they do exist, and can also be used as a noun. A "westerly" is wind coming ..."

May I say that country A lied westerlier than B, or would that be A lied westerly to B?

Comment: @AnatolyWein Forst - The past tense of lie is "lay", unless you meant that country A told an untruth - then it would have been "lied". And as regards preposition, I would say "Country A lay westerly **of** B"

Comment: The past tense of lie is "lay", unless you meant that country A told an untruth - then it would have been "lied". And as regards preposition, I would say "Country A lay westerly **of** B". Though if you want to speak American English, it could be different. Their choice of prepositions is often different to ours.

Comment: My bad, I mistyped, yes I meen "laid" (lay in the even more past tense). By the way, looks like instead of editing your comment was doubled) And I'd like to focus on the British English

Answer (score 3):

> I need to use phrases like "A is more souther than B",

"A is **further south** than B"

> https://brilliantmaps.com/cities-transposed-latitude/ "London (51°30′N) is farther north than Calgary (51°03′N) with Amsterdam, Berlin and Dublin being located even further north."

It seems that farther and further are used indiscriminately... I would use "further".

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  You can say "to the south of" if B is directly south from A (and usually relatively close, the implication being you can find B by going to A and then heading south).

Answer (score 2):

You would generally say "further South/East/West/North than"

Comment: But apparently the word "southern" exists. Yet easter(n) does not. Are there any other ways to say that?

Comment: Eastern exists as well as does Northern and Western. The -ern suffix means that something belongs to the region in that direction, so, for example one might talk of, e.g., Western libertarians referring to the rural libertarian-leaning people in the American West.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eastern Adjective forms of each cardinal direction exists.